# C - Freeing a pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

In my code I allocate a number of 2-dimensional arrays that I need to free up. However, every time I think I've grasped the concept of pointers, they keep surprising me by not doing what I expect them to ;)

So can anyone tell me how to deal with this situation?:

This is how I allocate memory for my pointers:

```
typedef struct HRTF_ {
  kiss_fft_cpx freqDataL[NFREQ]
  kiss_fft_cpx freqDataR[NFREQ]
  int nrSamples;
  char* fname;
} HRTF;

HRTF **_pHRTFs = NUL;
int _nHRTFs = 512;

_pHRTFs = (HRTF**) malloc( sizeof(HRTF*) *_nHRTFs );

int i = _nHRTFs;
while( i > 0 )
  _pHRTFs[--i] = (HRTF*) malloc( sizeof( HRTF ) );

// Load data into HRTF struct
```

And here's how I think I should be freeing the used memory:

```
if( _pHRTFs != NULL )
{
  __DEBUG( "Free mem used for HRTFs" );
  for( i = 0; i < _nHRTFs; ++i )
  {
    if( _pHRTFs[i] != NULL )
    {
      char buf[64];
      sprintf( buf, "Freeing mem for HRTF #%d", i );
      __DEBUG( buf );
      free( _pHRTFs[i] );
    }
  }
  __DEBUG( "Free array containing HRTFs" );
  free( _pHRTFs );
}
```

Freeing the individual `_pHRTFs[i]`'s works, the last `__DEBUG` statement is printed, but the last `free( _pHRTFs )` gives me a segmentation fault. Why?

**Nevermind** - Adding a debug statement after the last `free( _pHRTFs )` showed that this code is in fact working and that my problem lies somewhere else.. Thanks for your time!

Jonas

Comment: The code looks OK. Can you actually comment everything between allocation and free and see if it's still happening ?

Comment: How is the char *fname used? If you're allocating memory for it, you should free it before freeing the array holding the structs.

Comment: Code looks fine - please don't cast the result of malloc in C code though - it's not necessary and can mask errors that a compiler warning might otherwise reveal

Comment: I suspect there is some heap corruption occurring between when you allocate and when you free - try running your code under valgrind

Comment: The code ostensibly looks okay, assuming `_nHRTFs` has the same value (although there are a lot of things that are considered poor form: casting the result of `malloc`, not checking whether `malloc` succeeded, using `sizeof (T)` instead of `sizeof *var`, using `sprintf` instead of `snprintf`, naming things with leading underscores).

Answer (score 2):

The code is okay. I have tried running it and it works fine. Below is the code that I tested (I have replaced unknown datatypes with int) and output that I got which shows that there is nothing wrong here. The error you get is because of something else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct HRTF_ {
      int freqDataL[10];
      int freqDataR[10];
      int nrSamples;
      char* fname;
} HRTF;

HRTF **_pHRTFs = NULL;
int _nHRTFs = 512;

int main(){
    printf("allocatingi\n");
    _pHRTFs = (HRTF**) malloc( sizeof(HRTF*) *_nHRTFs );

    int i = _nHRTFs;
    while( i > 0 )
          _pHRTFs[--i] = (HRTF*) malloc( sizeof( HRTF ) );

    printf("Allocation complete. Now deallocating\n");
    for( i = 0; i < _nHRTFs; ++i )
    {
        if( _pHRTFs[i] != NULL )
        {
            char buf[64];
            sprintf( buf, "Freeing mem for HRTF #%d", i );
            //__DEBUG( buf );
            free( _pHRTFs[i] );
        }
    }
    printf("complete without error\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And output:

```
adnan@adnan-ubuntu-vm:desktop$ ./a.out 
allocatingi
Allocation complete. Now deallocating
complete without error
```

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocation and de-allocation seems fine. I, too compiled the above code after changing type to int and I got the below output. Problem lies somewhere else.

```
Freeing mem for HRTF #0
Freeing mem for HRTF #1
......
Freeing mem for HRTF #509
Freeing mem for HRTF #510
Freeing mem for HRTF #511
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, check whether you can shorten output.

Comment: I wanted complete output in this case to justify the correct free(). Even I don't intend to write long post.